# Prevent ghost script from auto rotating thumbnail

Tags: linux, pdf, thumbnails, ghostscript

I'm using ghostscript (gs) to create thumbnail of first page. The problem I'm facing is that sometimes it auto rotates the thumbnail.
Here's the command I'm using

```
gs -o thumb.jpeg -sDEVICE=jpeg -dLastPage=1 -dJPEGQ=100 -dPDFFitPage -g504x318 file.pdf
```

Is there any way to prevent gs from auto rotating on certain pdf files

Comment: Probably, yes, don't specify -dPDFFitPage. I cannot be certain without seeing the input PDF file, but it seems likely that the reason it is auto-rotating is because the requested media size fits the fixed media size (-g) better, ie with less scaling, if it is rotated. If you don't want that then you'll have to code the scaling yourself because that's the way that PDFFitPage works. There's documentation on scripting the interpreter here https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Language.html#scripting-the-pdf-interpreter

Comment: Hi, when I remove `-dPDFFitPage` it generate a white thumbnail. as the first page of the pdf that I'm testing have some white space. These pdfs are uploaded by the user so I cannot know beforehand what they look like.

Comment: If you remove PDFFitPage then it won't (obviously) fit the content to the page, resulting in only a small portion being drawn. My point is that the code is doing what it's supposed to, if you don't want that then you'll need to take action yourself to do it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KJ mention to make sure the thumbnail does not rotate. First make a square thumbnail like this

```
gs -o thumb.jpeg -sDEVICE=jpeg -dLastPage=1 -dJPEGQ=100 -dPDFFitPage -g504x504 file.pdf
```

than crop out the thumbnail to ideal size using another tool
like sharp (for nodejs)

```
await sharp("thumb.jpeg")
       .extract({width: 504, height: 314, top: 0, left: 0});
```